# How can i cache the result of rand()?

Tags: php, caching

I want to cache the result of rand() for 5 minutes.

```
<?php

$sec = 300;
$expires = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $sec) . " GMT";
header("Expires: $expires");
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=$sec");

echo "Test " . rand(1, 10);
```

Unfortunately, i don't know why my code doesn't work. Everytime i call the php file in my browser the random number is different.
Does anybody has an idea what the problem is?

**Edit:**
The headers are sent correctly, but everytime I reload the page, the `Expires` header changes.
When i print `$_SERVER`, The `HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL` header says `no-cache`.
Could that be the problem?

Comment: An alternative could be to store it in a session and unset that session after 5 minutes, is that not possible?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is just a snippet to understand why it's not working. I want to achieve something else with caching. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: To cache it like that I think you need to set your htaccess to cache PHP files

Comment: When else should you use these http headers, if not for caching?

Comment: It might be an over kill, you can save the value in redis.

Comment: Do you explicitly refresh the page? Then you're probably explicitly bypassing the browser cache. You'll have to define better where and for whom that value needs to be cached.

Comment: I just noticed that the 'Expires' header is also changing every time i reload the page. Could that be the reason that it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe just explain your use case to us, there's usually better approaches to things like this. You can't cache a function's outcome without saving it somewhere.

Comment: But when else are the caching headers used?

Comment: _“But when else are the caching headers used?”_ - when the client has to decide whether it should request a resource again from the server, or use its cached version …? With an “explicit” reload in your browser, you of course overwrite whatever any headers instructed in that regard. You can not “force” usage of a client-side cache that way, you can only _advise_ it.

Comment: It tells the browser how long it can store the result without contacting the server again. That does not mean the browser won't ever contact the server again under any circumstances within that timeframe. If you explicitly refresh the page for example, it will ignore the cached version.

Comment: thank you very much, this is the answer i was searching for. i totally misunderstood the caching headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, everyone here suggesting alternatives, including javascript, cookies, etc but that does NOT answer the question.

The question is to cache using headers for that explicitly a 304 NOT Modified response exists...

```
<?php
$sec = 300;
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']))
{
    $if_modified=time($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']);
    if($if_modified>time()-$sec)
    {
        Header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
        exit();
    }

}

$expires = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $sec) .' '. date_default_timezone_get();
$modified= gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time()) . ' '.date_default_timezone_get();
header("Expires: $expires");
header("Last-Modified: $modified");
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=$sec");

echo "Test " . rand(1, 10);
```

There you go.
Caching random numbers with headers.

Answer (score 0):

```
I want to cache the result of rand() for 5 minutes.It can be possible throw javascript code. But it store in cookie

// this fun call after every 5 miniute
setInterval(function(){ 
    generate_and_cookie_random_fun();   
}, 5000);

// this fun generate random number and sotre it to cookie
function generate_and_cookie_random_fun(){
  var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1 ;
  setCookie('name_of_cookie',random_number ,7);  // here 7 mean seven days
}

// below code for cookie 
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
function eraseCookie(name) {   
    document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;';  
}
```

Comment: It is tagged PHP. There is not mention of JavaScript.

Comment: `var random_number = rand(1, 10);` - What is `rand`? That isn't a JavaScript function.

Comment: `// this fun call after every 5 miniute` - No, it will be called every 5 seconds.

Comment: `// this fun generate random number and sotre it to cache` - No, it stores it in a cookie.

Comment: Math.random() is available in javascript

Comment: Yes, `Math.random` is, but `rand` isn't.

Answer (score -1):

The simple way is to store it into cookie and check that if cookie exists to show the stored number, otherwise generate new.

Something like this:

```
<?php
setcookie("random_number", rand(1, 10), time() + 300);

if(isset($_COOKIE['random_number'])) {
echo $_COOKIE['random_number'];
} else {
setcookie("random_number", rand(1, 10), time() + 300);    
}
```

Comment: Not quite what the OP is asking as explained already in the comments

Comment: thank you, but i need to solve it with caching, isn't that possible?

Comment: I didn't see your comment before my posting.. (:

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://andidittrich.de/2015/09/php-worry-about-some-magical-added-cache-control-header.html

Comment: Thank you, but the headers are sent correctly. 
`Cache-Control →max-age=300
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Type →text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date →Mon, 30 Jul 2018 09:21:04 GMT
Etag →d11f294a511261ea8fd9daf219537760
Expires →Mon, 30 Jul 2018 09:26:04 GMT
Pragma →cache
Server →nginx/1.15.1
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
X-Powered-By →PHP/7.2.8`

Comment: Anyway, did you try adding session_cache_limiter(''); to the beginning of your file?

Comment: This would be an acceptable answer to solve a problem like mine. Even if it doesn't work in my case, I will accept this answer because it could help others.

Comment: @LucaRath-Heel it is your choice which answer you accept but the reason you have mentioned above is incorrect. People coming to this question will be wanting to try and solve the issue in the question, this answer does solve it but there is no caching involved.

Comment: That is your choice. If you feel this answer solved your issue, leave it.

Comment: Other users who come across this question will probably read the comments too, so they'll see this conversation. they can decide for themselves what they accept. i think that this answer helps a few of them, so i let it marked as accepted.